AOSP: how to read global settings from framework system code (without activity/context)?
From AOSP's framework code, I am trying to read Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, the obvious API being Settings.Global#getInt .
getInt expects a ContentResolver as parameter. I understand (briefly) this is usually derived from the apps current activity/context. However, the framework code I work on is part of the Android PackageManager, and not really related to any activity.
AFAIK, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED is a global setting. PackageManager is running with system permissions. Is there a technical reason why I need a ContentResolver? Is there such a thing like a global static ContentResolver that can be used by system code?
